# Proving the conditions of projection of a given point on a cone that are related to its dual-cone.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have the definition of dual cone as $K^*=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n|\langle y,x\rangle\geq0 \forall{x}\in{K}\}$, where $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty closed convex cone. 
For a given point $\hat{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we should show that $x^*\in{K}$ is the projection of $\hat{x}$ on the cone $K$ if and only if:

1. $x^*-\hat{x}\in{K}^*$
2. $\langle{x^*-\hat{x},x^*}\rangle=0$

How should I prove these conditions?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $K$ is a convex set and $P_{K}(x)$ is the projection of $x$ onto $K$, it satisfies

$$
\langle x - P_K(x), y - P_K(x) \rangle \leq 0, \; \forall y \in K.
$$

Since $K$ is closed, it follows that $0 \in K$. Therefore, substituting $y = 0$ yields

$$
\langle P_K(x) - x, P_K(x)\rangle \leq 0.
\qquad (1)
$$

On the other hand, since $K$ is a cone, we have $y \in K \Rightarrow \lambda y \in K$ for any nonnegative $\lambda$. Substituting $y = \lambda P_K(x)$ in the same inequality, we obtain

$$
\langle x - P_K(x), (\lambda - 1) P_K(x) \rangle \leq 0 \Leftrightarrow
\langle P_K(x) - x, (\lambda - 1) P_K(x) \rangle \geq 0.
$$

Setting $\lambda = 2$ above, we recover that

$$
\langle P_K(x) - x, P_K(x) \rangle \geq 0. \qquad (2)
$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ yields $\langle P_K(x) - x, P_K(x) \rangle = 0$, which is the second item in your question.

I'll leave the first item up to you, since it follows easily once you have the second one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It may seem a simple question, but how did you get the inequality in the first line?

Comment: The first inequality follows from the first-order optimality condition of the problem $$\min_z \frac{1}{2} \| x - z \|^2: z \in K,$$
whose solution is the projection $P_K(x)$.